# Weird display errors in Windows GDI+ application

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, gdi+

I am facing a strange problem while using GDI+ to draw the user interface of an application. Sometimes there are display errors showing artifacts of other applications. Sometimes the borders of my text controls are drawn completely in black.

In some cases the problem is also more than a simple display error. When that happens I have a menu or a context menu from another application embedded into my application. This menu is not only visible, but you can also highlight menu entries by hovering above them with your mouse and expand submenus. However there is no functionallity behind them when you click on the entries. It seems to be that these menus are always part of the Windows Explorer.

I have no clue where I should start my search for the cause of these problems. Perhaps someone here at SO can point me to a possible source of the problem or even a solution?

**Clarification:** The same code shows this error on multiple PCs with different hardware, different graphic card drivers and different operating systems (XP, Win7, Server 2008). I would love to post some code, but it is very complex and wide-spread throughout the application. And since I have no clue what could be the root cause of the problems, I cannot isolate the right part the code.

**Here are some screenshots:**

Black borders around my text controls and my panel control:

[image]

Content of another application is drawn inside my applications window. You can see a context menu from the Windows explorer on the left and parts of an excel sheet on the right. The grid-table in the lower part of the form is normally directly under the window titlebar:
Display error in form showing context menu of explorer:

[image]

Comment: We need more information, please: the same code has the same problem on lots of different PCs, or just one?  Different code has the same problem on your PC?  Have you tried upgrading your graphics drivers?  Care to show us some code? etc

Comment: _Sometimes the borders of my text controls are drawn completely in black_ Are you sure there are no GDI handle leaks?

Comment: I fixed some leaking GDI object. But the issues are still there.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you embed another application, i guess that you are using classic GDI calls together with GDI+? Thats a tedious thing. I did the same and it caused several problems where some parts of my program were not drawn and became invisible.

The solution to me was (and is) to always destroy all Gdiplus::Graphics before using GDI-Functions - alternatively you may try calling Graphics::Flush.

After all i must resume that starting to use GDI+ was a bad idea, and mixing it into a existing GDI Application was a horrible idea. You should use only one API (Maybe rather direct3D). GDI+ is not based on GDI - obviously both work in parallel.

I just found this article describing some limitations of mixing GDI and GDI+: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311221/info-interoperability-between-gdi-and-gdi

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I am not embedding another application. This behavior is part of the errors we are facing. The context menu from the Windows explorer which is displayed sometimes inside our application is part of the symptoms of the error.

Comment: And yes, we indeed mix up between GDI and GDI+. Did you have similar behavior?

Comment: @RED SOFT ADAIR, Could you provide a link to any resource that says that you cannot mix GDI and GDI+?

Comment: No, i can't - its just me painful experience.

Comment: Not wishing to be provocative, but I've mixed GDI and GDI+ without any problems for many years. GDI+ is generally easier to use but GDI is sometimes a LOT faster (especially working with bitmaps) so I've found it really helpful to use both at the same time to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: So you are lucky. I had no problems at first either. But i draw graf where thousands of GDI and GDI+ are drawn in random order, and after a while users reported vanishing areas. I was able to fix that - by forced flushing of GDI+.

Comment: I've honestly never encountered anything like what you describe when mixing GDI and GDI+. I've also had thousands of objects being drawn to the screen and it works perfectly. The reason I used GDI as well as GDI+ was for performance when double buffering - my application needed to be flicker free and using GDI for some of the bitmap operations gave a huge performance improvement. There's nothing I'm aware of which says mixing GDI and GDI+ can't be done (in fact the documentation suggests is perfectly possible).

Comment: What are you trying to say? That the problems that i encountered, tracked down and solved did not exist?